# Getting a Flash Movie with Javascript in IE

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, cross-browser, swfobject

I have a flash movie that I need to get with javascript.

Here is how I embed it using [swf object](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/):

```
<div id="ap1_mod"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var flashvars = {
        mp3Path: "stop",
        artistName : "",
        trackName : ""
    };
    var params = {
        codebase: 'http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0',
        src: '/public/flash/ap1_mod.swf',
        quality: 'high',
        pluginspage: 'http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer',
        scale: 'showall',
        devicefont: 'false',
        bgcolor: '#999999',
        name: 'ap1_mod',
        menu: 'true',
        allowFullScreen: 'false',
        allowScriptAccess:'always', //sameDomain
        movie: '/public/flash/ap1_mod.swf',
    wmode: "transparent",
    allowfullscreen: "true"
    };

    swfobject.embedSWF("/public/flash/ap1_mod.swf", "ap1_mod", "400", "50", "9.0.0", false, flashvars, params);
</script>
```

and here is how I try to access it:

```
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
  var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
  return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}
```

As usual, it's working fine in Firefox and Safari, but it's breaking in IE. If I add an alert: to display what returns getFlashMovie I get "undefined".

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, embedSWF replaces the element you specify with the object, so you'd just use:

```
var movie = document.getElementById("ap1_mod");
```

I haven't actually checked but because the div element is being replaced with an object element, it's possible it isn't re-registered as a property of window in IE.

Comment: It fixed it! I didn't think of doing this. I'm always surprise by how this way to embed swf makes life easier. thanks

Comment: No problem, glad that fixed it for you.

Answer (score 1):

Could you specify an `id` in the `params` and then just use:

```
document.getElementById( 'theId' );
```

To reference the `<object>` that gets created by swfobject?